# How to make a swift Codable struct for the following json data ( I am using URLSession.dataTask in Swiftui to get the data)?

Tags: json, swift, api

I require data from World Bank API for my iOS app (I am using SwiftUI). Some of the API calls have json data begin and end in curly brackets ({}),and making a Swift Codable struct for the same is simple.

However some of the API calls return JSON data which start with square brackets ([]),thus a list of several dictionaries. I do not know how to construct a swift Codable struct for the same. Please help me out. I am currently importing it as a jsonString and carrying out splits and several other operations to get the desired format, however this method is very tedious as well as time consuming since the json data is of great length.

An example of the json data for which I need help making a Swift Codable struct is given below :

> [{"page":1,"pages":16226,"per_page":1,"total":16226,"sourceid":"2","sourcename":"World Development Indicators","lastupdated":"2021-07-30"},[{"indicator":{"id":"AG.AGR.TRAC.NO","value":"Agricultural machinery, tractors"},"country":{"id":"ZH","value":"Africa Eastern and Southern"},"countryiso3code":"AFE","date":"2020","value":null,"unit":"","obs_status":"","decimal":0}]]

The link for the actual data which I am working with is given below (I have simply copy and pasted a part of it here since the original data is a lot longer) :
http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/AG.AGR.TRAC.NO?format=json&per_page=32500

Comment: copy and paste the json data into "https://quicktype.io/" and use that to generate your data structures.

Comment: I didn't know about this site. Thanks a lot, @workingdog for the tip! +

Comment: I tried using the struct made via QuickType.io, however when used with JsonDecoder after getting the data, it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving an array that contains different data types : in your example a single "object" then an array.

The object contains informations about the response itself (number of pages, etc. `Metadata`). The array contains the records themselves (`[ApiRecord]`)
What should give this kind of model (simplified) :

```
struct Metadata: Codable {
    let page: Int
    let sourceid: String
}

struct ApiRecord: Codable {
    let indicator: Indicator
    let country: Country
    let decimal: Int
}
struct Country: Codable {
    let id, value: String
}

struct Indicator: Codable {
    let id, value: String
}
```

Now, for your response we will define an enum (with associated values).
Your api response will be decoded into an array of different enum cases (with associated value : Metadata or [ApiRecord].

```
typealias ApiResponse = [ReponseType]

enum ReponseType: Codable {
    case metadata(Metadata)
    case apiRecordArray([ApiRecord])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let record = try? container.decode([ApiRecord].self) {
            self = .apiRecordArray(record)
            return
        }
        if let record = try? container.decode(Metadata.self) {
            self = .metadata(record)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ReponseType.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Error"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .metadata(let record):
            try container.encode(record)
        case .apiRecordArray(let record):
            try container.encode(record)
        }
    }
}
```